# okta shibboleth attribute configuration not working

Tags: attributes, shibboleth, okta

I am trying to extract an attribute from Okta.

In Okta I have
[Okta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a8ho.png)

However I can't seem to get the attribute map correct. I tried playing around and according to [this](https://www.assetbank.co.uk/support/documentation/knowledge-base/how-can-i-connect-okta-my-shibboleth-enabled-asset-bank/) I tried

```
<Attribute name="mail" nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified" id="mail">
```

However that didn't work. I tried looking at [OKTA integration issue with Shibboleth SP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137111/okta-integration-issue-with-shibboleth-sp) but none of the answers seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

My fault, I omitted some things. When I use the full xml it works.

```
    <Attribute name="email" nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified" id="email">
        <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="StringAttributeDecoder"/>
    </Attribute>
```